# How show total price in my text widget in flutter

Tags: flutter, sum, sqflite

I want show total price in flutter ui with tezt widget. I tried raw query

```
var sonuc=await db.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(gelirTutar) FROM gelirIslem");
```

it returned QueryResultSet the result [{SUM(gelirTutar): 70.0}] and it is making an error Unhandled Exception: type 'List>' is not a subtype of type 'String'

How can I display "70.0" data in my text widget

this code my sum method

```
Future gelirTopla()async{
    var db=await _getDatabase();
    var sonuc=await db.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(gelirTutar) FROM gelirIslem");

   print("gelir:"+sonuc.toString());
    return sonuc;
  }
```

and this code UI design

```
class KasaIslem extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _KasaIslemState createState() => _KasaIslemState();
}

class _KasaIslemState extends State<KasaIslem> {
  double toplamGelir;
  DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    databaseHelper=DatabaseHelper();
    setState(() {
      gelirHesapla();

    });
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Kasa İşlemleri"),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[


                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                              child: Text(
                                "Günlük Gelir:",
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.redAccent),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                              child: Text(
                                toplamGelir.toString(),
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.redAccent),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),

                      ],
                    ),
                  );


  }

  void gelirHesapla() async{
    var toplam=await databaseHelper.gelirTopla();
    setState(() {
      print("ttt"+toplam.toList());
      toplamGelir=toplam;
    });


  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `rawQuery` always returns a List of Maps so you need to extract the string out. If you update the query to:

```dart
var sonuc=await db.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(gelirTutar) as sum FROM gelirIslem");
```

then the result should be `[{sum: 70.0}]` so you can do `sonuc.first["sum"]` to get the count.

Comment: it is ok. the result "gelir:70.0" but it is make an error Class 'double' has no instance method 'toList'.

Comment: That's because of your print statement `print("ttt"+toplam.toList())`. Looking at your code `toplam` should be a double anyway so if you remove this line `gelirHesapla()` should work. Since `toplam` is a double a better print statement is `print("ttt $toplam")` as this will convert the double into a string as it's output